# Text editor program stops working TASM 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I ran into a problem while writing code for my task. What the program is supposed to do is this: at the end of the sentence, when i encounter a period (.) I am supposed to check if there is a space after the period and if the first letter of the next sentence is capital. So this is a part of my code which does the job. However when I run the program it doesn't do anything and the cursor just blinks without the program ever closing or displaying the edited sentences.

```
MOV cx, ax
    MOV si, offset readBuff           ;read buffer
    MOV di, offset writeBuff          ;write buffer
    MOV bl, 97                        ;lowercase 'a'
    MOV bh, 122                       ;lowercase 'z'
  work:

    MOV dl, [si]                      ;
    CMP dl, '.'                       ;check if symbol is a period
    JNE continue                      ;if no, then just print the symbol
    MOV dh, [si+1]                    ;if it is a period move next symbol to dh
    CMP dh, ' '                       ; check if it is a space
    JNE add_space                     ;if no, then go to add space
    MOV dh, [si+2]                    ;put the first letter of the sentence to dh
    cmp dh, bl                        ;compare it to 'a'
    jb  continue                      ;if below then print the symbol
    cmp dh, bh                        ;compare it to 'z'
    ja  continue                      ;if above then print the symbol
    sub byte ptr [si+2], 32           ;if lowercase, then make it uppercase

  continue:

    MOV [di], dl                      ;write symbol to writeBuffer
    INC si                            
    INC di
    LOOP work

  add_space:
    MOV [di], '.'                     ;first add a period
    INC di        
    MOV [di], ' '                     ;then a space; argument needs type override error
    INC di
    INC si
    CMP cx, 0
    JNE work                          ;go back to work
```

Comment: Shouldn't you decrement `cx` by 2 and compare against 0 in the `add_space` case? Also, there's no need to ASCII codes like 97 and 122 in your program since you can just write `'a'` and `'z'`.

Comment: Because you never close, or print anything. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Also, consider what happens when the `LOOP work` in the `continue` case doesn't jump because `cx` reached 0.

Comment: @Sneftel are you even serious right now?

Comment: @Michael I doubt i should dec cx by 2 since then i wouldn't get through the whole readBuff during the loop, wouldn't I?

Comment: You should at least increment `si`, and decrement `cx` based on how  far you moved `si`.

Comment: Step through it in debug and let us know if this happens: You see a period, but not a space, so then you put a period and a space in `writeBuff`.  Then you return back to `work:`, where `si` is (still?) pointing to the same period, which has the same non-space after it.  

From that point, I see a strong possibility for an infinite loop.  See if that's the case.

Comment: Clarification, please.  When you write "...* when i hit a period (.) I am supposed to check*..."  the word "hit" means "encounter", as opposed to physically typing at the keyboard; yes ?  i.e., "*I hit*" means that your program encounters the period character.  Is this the case ?

Comment: @User.1 thanks for your input, now that i think about it, it most likely was an infinite loop, however inc si did not do the trick. And yes, what i mean is encounter a period.

Comment: Thanks to Michael and @User.1 i managed to get out of the infinite loop. However, the output is wrong. The program does not change the letter to uppercase if it was lowercase and the last symbol of the buffer seems to get lost.

Comment: @DominykasBer ,   Can your debugger break into frozen code ?